# Search while Type functionality on VFP not working as expected between apex:tab transition

Tags: visualforce, javascript, javascript-remoting, search

I have 2 apex:tabs (Primary Tab, Secondary Tab) in visualforce page which shows a table of accounts list. I have a custom script for "search-while typing" functionality with below script. 
//VFP

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" controller="customController" standardStylesheets="true">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/JavaScript" />
<apex:form id="formId">
    <apex:pageBlock Title="Accounts List" mode="inlineEdit" id="acc_list" >
    <apex:pagemessages />
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
             <apex:commandButton action="{!Edit}" id="editButton" value="Edit"/>
             <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" id="saveButton" value="Save"/>
             <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" onclick="resetInlineEdit()" id="cancelButton" value="Cancel"/>
             &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
             <input type="text" id="inputAccountName" onkeyup="searchByAccountName()" placeholder="Search by Account..." title="Type in an Account Name"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
<apex:tabPanel title="Accounts" id="tabpanelId" tabClass="activeTab" inactiveTabClass="inactiveTab" value="{!varTabId}">
<!-------- Primary Tab -------->
<apex:tab label="Primary" name="Primary" switchType="ajax" id="Primary" ontabenter="setActiveTab();">
<!-- *** Primary Detail Mode*** -->
        <apex:pageMessage summary="No Primary Accounts were assigned to you.<br/><br/> Please change the Account's ownership to your name inorder for them to be visible here. <br/><br/>Thank You!" escape="false" severity="Info" strength="3" rendered="{!lstaAccs.size=0}" />
        <apex:outputpanel rendered="{!AND(view,lstaAccs.size>0)}" id="viewPrimaryDetail">
            <apex:actionStatus id="loadingPrimaryDetail" >
                <apex:facet name="start" >
                  <center><img src="/img/loading32.gif" />      Loading....  Please Wait...  </center>
                </apex:facet>
            </apex:actionStatus>
            <div class="table-container">
            <div class="heading-bg"></div>
                <div class="table-container-inner">
                    <table id="schTablePrimaryDetail" >
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <td><div class="heading" style="width: 60px;word-wrap:break-word;">
                                     <apex:commandLink value="Account Name" action="{!toggleSort}" style="text-decoration: none;" rerender="formId" status="loading">
                                        <apex:param name="sortField" value="Name" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                                    </apex:commandLink></div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <apex:repeat value="{!lstaAccs}" var="a">
                            <tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#e3f3ff';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffffff';">
                            <td><div style="width: 80px;word-wrap:break-word;">
                            <apex:outputLink value="/{!a.Acc.Id}" id="acclinkPrimaryDetail" title="Account Name">{!a.Acc.name}</apex:outputLink></div></td>                              
                            </tr>
                            </apex:repeat>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </apex:outputpanel>


<!-------- Secondary Tab -------->
    <apex:tab label="Secondary" name="Secondary" switchType="ajax" id="Secondary" ontabenter="setActiveSecondaryTab();">
<!-- *** Secondary Detail Mode*** -->
        <apex:pageMessage summary="No Secondary Accounts were assigned to you." severity="Info" strength="3" rendered="{!lstaAccs.size=0}"/>
        <apex:outputpanel rendered="{!AND(view,lstaAccs.size>0)}" id="viewSecondaryDetail">
            <apex:actionStatus id="loadingSecondaryDetail" >
                <apex:facet name="start" >
                  <center><img src="/img/loading32.gif" />      Loading....  Please Wait...  </center>
                </apex:facet>
            </apex:actionStatus>
            <div class="table-container">
            <div class="heading-bg"></div>
                <div class="table-container-inner">
                    <table id="schTableSecondaryDetail">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <td><div class="heading" style="width: 60px;word-wrap:break-word;">
                                     <apex:commandLink value="Account Name" action="{!toggleSort}" style="text-decoration: none;" rerender="formId" status="loading">
                                        <apex:param name="sortField" value="Name" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                                    </apex:commandLink></div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <apex:repeat value="{!lstaAccs}" var="a">
                            <tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#e3f3ff';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffffff';">
                            <td><div style="width: 80px;word-wrap:break-word;">
                            <apex:outputLink value="/{!a.Acc.Id}" id="acclinkSecondaryDetail" title="Account Name">{!a.Acc.name}</apex:outputLink></div></td>
                            </tr>
                            </apex:repeat>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </apex:outputpanel>
    </apex:tabPanel> 


    <apex:actionFunction action="{!setActiveSecondaryTab}" name="setActiveSecondaryTab"/>
```

`<apex:actionFunction action="{!setActiveTab}" name="setActiveTab"/>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
    <script>
        // Account Search script
        function searchByAccountName() {
            var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue, multipletables;
            input = document.getElementById("inputAccountName");
            filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
            multipletables = ["schTablePrimaryDetail","schTable1PrimaryEdit","schTableSecondaryDetail","schTable1SecondaryEdit"];
            var x = multipletables.length;
            for (var k = 0; k < multipletables.length; k++){
                table = document.getElementById(multipletables[k]);
                tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
                for (i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {
                    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
                    if (td) {
                    txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                            tr[i].style.display = "";
                        } else {
                            tr[i].style.display = "none";
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</apex:page>`[image: VFP with input text box on top]

The functionality works just fine on Primary Tab where the accountName typed in the input "text" would show the corresponding account from the list of accounts with in the table. However it wont work on Secondary Tab and I'm unable to figure out/ debug what went wrong where the functionality won't work when switched to other tab. Please let me know what i'm missing here. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: not working as expected is not a very useful problem description, you will have to do some debugging an highlight exactly what seems to 'not work' as well as any errors, or code related pointers that might help identify the behavior.

Comment: @glls Hi glls, I tried to make it clean with snap of actual VFP. I have searchByAccountName() function which is called on top looking for account name from both the tables. However, secondary tab as shown above wouldn't let the searchByAccountName() run or I'm not sure what is blocking it. Please give me your inputs based of what i have. Thanks!

Comment: no, sorry, i'm not going to go through your code to try and guess what the issue might be, please edit your post with what "debugging" you have done so far,  it will be easier to provide feedback

Comment: @glls To be fair, this isn't easy to debug. I only happened to know the answer because I had a similar need years ago.

Comment: @sfdcfox thank you much, really appreciate your response. Will try that out and share my findings.

Comment: I was merely pointing out that given the lack of details (other than behavioral), I personally was not willing to further invest time on this. glad that you were able to answer based on past experience. @SMorse, sorry if I sounded rude - it was not my intention.

Comment: @sfdcfox - I did replace switch with "Client" but however once clicked on secondarytab & entered the Search text, it is unable to do the smart search. Tried the code you shared & it works perfectly for a one column table but when I tried to replace my script with the one you shared & as the "querySelectorAll" is on td which looks for the text in all td's across all the columns, it is then unable to show the complete row instead shows wrong format results as shown in newly attached snap. Is there a way I can make the script i wrote work for secondary tab as i show/hide tr based of td.

Comment: @sfdcfox hi sfdcfox, not sure if you got a chance to take at look at my response. The search while type in still not working for secondary tab. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The "AJAX" type switch mode results in a round-trip to the server and the DOM is regenerated. This wipes out any changes that may have been made to the DOM by the client since the last update. Change the switchType attribute to "client." Self-contained example follows.

```
<apex:page >
    <script>
        function filter() {
            var searchTerm = (document.querySelector("#search").value || '').toUpperCase();
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(
                document.querySelectorAll("td.data"),
                function(row) {
                    row.style.display = row.innerText && row.innerText.toUpperCase().indexOf(searchTerm) > -1?'inherit':'none';
                }
            );
        }
    </script>
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
            <input id="search" type="search" onkeyup="filter()" />
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:tabPanel switchType="client">
            <apex:tab label="Tab 1">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <th>Name</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="data">Demo 1</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="data">Demo 2</td>
                        </tr>                        
                        <tr>
                            <td class="data">Demo 1: 2</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="data">Demo 2: 4</td>
                        </tr>                        
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </apex:tab>
            <apex:tab label="Tab 2">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <th>Name</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="data">Demo 3</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="data">Demo 4</td>
                        </tr>                        
                        <tr>
                            <td class="data">Demo 3: 1</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="data">Demo 4: 2</td>
                        </tr>                        
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </apex:tab>
        </apex:tabPanel>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Note also that if you use reRender to update part of the page, you must *also* use an `oncomplete` to call the `filter()` function again to restore the desired search state.

Comment: Tried to incorporate similar thing but it still doesnt work on tab2. Please let me know if i need to consider anything else